# how to bypass preventDefault method

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to validate some fields and display error messages when the required fields are not filled out.  In my form, I have a section for an alternate address.  If the user selects a checkbox for the alternate address, I make the street, city, state and zip required and use preventDefault to stop the form from submitting until those fields are filled out.  The preventDefault method is stopping the form from getting submitted if the alternate address checkbox is selected.

Can a jquery expert take a look at my code and let me know how I can bypass the preventDefault when the alternate address checkbox is selected and all the required fields are correctly filled out?

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
        var submitButton = j$('[id$=btnSubmit]');
        var emailButton = j$('[id$=btnEmail]');
        var shippingMethod = j$('[id$=shippingMethod]');
        var alternateAddress = j$('[id$=chkbxAlternateAddress]');
        var alternateStreet = j$('[id$=alternateaddress]');
        var alternateCity = j$('[id$=alternatecity]');
        var alternateState = j$('[id$=alternatestate]');
        var alternateZip = j$('[id$=alternatezip]');
        submitButton.click(function(e){
            j$('[id$=documentQuantity]').each(function(index){
                if(j$(this).text() == '0') {
                    j$("#contentQtyError").css({"display":"inline"});
                    j$(this).parent().parent().css({"background-color":"#FFFFCC"});
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });             
            if(shippingMethod.val() == '') {
                if(j$('.shippingMethodErrorMsg').length == 0) {
                    shippingMethod.after("<span class='shippingMethodErrorMsg'>Error: A Shipping Method is Required</span>");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                j$(".shippingMethodErrorMsg").remove();
            }
            if(alternateAddress.attr("checked")) {
                if(j$('.alternateStreetErrorMsg').length == 0) {
                    alternateStreet.after("<span class='alternateStreetErrorMsg'>Error: A Street Address is Required</span>");
                }
                if(j$('.alternateCityErrorMsg').length == 0) {
                    alternateCity.after("<span class='alternateCityErrorMsg'>Error: A City is Required</span>");
                }
                if(j$('.alternateStateErrorMsg').length == 0) {
                    alternateState.after("<span class='alternateStateErrorMsg'>Error: A State is Required</span>");
                }
                if(j$('.alternateZipErrorMsg').length == 0) {
                    alternateZip.after("<span class='alternateZipErrorMsg'>Error: A Zip is Required</span>");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                j$(".alternateStreetErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateCityErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateStateErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateZipErrorMsg").remove();
            }
        });
        shippingMethod.change(function(){
            if(shippingMethod.val() == 'Email') {
                emailButton.css({"display":""});
                submitButton.css({"display":"none"});
                j$('#containerAltAddressToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxAlternateAddress]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('[id$=alternateAddressPanel]').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('#containerCustomKitToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxCustomKit]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('[id$=customKitPanel]').css({"display":"none"});             
                j$('#containerPersonalNoteToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxPersonalNote]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('[id$=personalNotePanel]').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('#containerFollowUpTaskToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxScheduleTask]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('#recurrence').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=commentsBlock]').css({"display":"none"});
            }
            else {
                emailButton.css({"display":"none"});
                submitButton.css({"display":""});
                j$('#containerAltAddressToggle').css({"display":""});
                j$('#containerCustomKitToggle').css({"display":""});                
                j$('#containerPersonalNoteToggle').css({"display":""});
                j$('#containerFollowUpTaskToggle').css({"display":""}); 
                j$('[id$=nextTask]').val("");   
                j$('[id$=commentsBlock]').css({"display":""});      
            }                           
        });
        alternateAddress.change(function() {
            if(alternateAddress.attr("checked") != "checked") {
                j$(".alternateStreetErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateCityErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateStateErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateZipErrorMsg").remove();
            }
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a form, then it's perhaps better to use an event listener on the form submission. Then, to do what you want, do this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   // do all of your validation

   // if everything is OK, submit the form
   $(this).submit();
});
```

Have a look at the jQuery Docs [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

to bypass preventdefoult you must add a listener in bubbling `addEventListener('event',function,true);`

or set the css pointer-event:none at html element

```
   #elementId{pointer-events: none}
```

that delete all event on this element

in this case I suggest you to use a simple button not a submit and use $("#elementId").submit(); to do the submit by code